# Update value of one table with other values of same column with different condition in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help?

I have a table with different values for `2 SiteID` and i am trying replace of one `sited id` with the values of another in the same table.I want the values of when `site id =158` with the values of when `site id =56`

Result 1 : `Site id =158`

```
Dt           C-Id  M-Id    Values
01/03/2014  14354   6   25504.3047
01/03/2014  15266   6   25504.3047
01/03/2014  14354   10  25504.3047
01/03/2014  14354   15  25504.3047
01/03/2014  15266   15  25504.3047
01/03/2014  14354   16  25504.3047
```

Result 2 : `Site id = 56`

```
Dt          C-Id   M-Id Values
01/03/2014  14354   6   11915
01/03/2014  15266   6   536
01/03/2014  14354   10  1517
01/03/2014  14354   15  3662
01/03/2014  15266   15  1071
01/03/2014  14354   16  3662
```

I wrote this query:

```
UPDATE [WorkDb].[dbo].[M_values]
SET [value] = (
        SELECT O.[value]
        FROM [WorkDb].[dbo].[M_values] AS O
        WHERE O.siteid IN (56)
            AND O.DATE = '2014-03-01'
            AND O.C - Id IN (14354, 15266)
            AND O.M - Id IN (6, 10, 15, 16, 25, 55, 56, 18)
            AND ISNULL(O.value, 0) <> 0
        )
WHERE (
        siteid IN (158)
        AND DATE = '2014-03-01'
        AND C - Id IN (14354,15266)
        AND M - Id IN (6,10,15,16,25,55,56,18)
        AND ISNULL(value, 0) <> 0
        )
```

This query returns error :

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: Your subquery produces more than one result. If two records are generated by your subquery, which value should be used?

Comment: Also, should Site 56's c-id and m-id match Site 158's c-id and m-id?

Comment: Yes the values are more than one... i mean the rows are more than one. I need to replace the values of site ID =158 with the values of sited id =56

Comment: Yes it does...to confirm that i have placed the table for 2 results with those siteIds

Comment: Ok based on your comment, I've provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not joining on the correct criteria to get a single record.

```
UPDATE mv
SET [value] = site56.[value]
FROM [WorkDb].[dbo].[M_values] mv
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT O.[value],O.[date],O.[C-Id],O.[M-Id]
    FROM [WorkDb].[dbo].[M_values] as O
    WHERE O.siteid IN (56)
    and ISNULL(O.value,0)<>0
) site56 ON site56.[date]=mv.[date] AND site56.[C-Id]=mv.[C-Id] AND site56.[M-Id]=mv.[M-Id]
WHERE (
    mv.siteid IN (158)
    AND mv.[date] = '2014-03-01'
    and mv.[C-Id] IN (14354,15266)
    and mv.[M-Id] IN (6,10,15,16,25,55,56,18)
    and ISNULL(mv.[value],0)<>0
)
```